# Firebase, event kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification never fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nsnotificationcenter

I add an **observer** on the event **kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification**

```
[FIRApp configure];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
             selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:) 
             name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token] => It's null at this moment
```

i check if everything is well configured by sending myself the kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification event via postNotificationName, it's work i receive the event

I delete the application from the iphone to be sure that token must be recreated

just after doing addObserver i check `[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]` and **it's null** so for sure it's will be created later

but no way the `kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification` is never fired :( i wait few second and check again `[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]` and it's not null anymore but the `kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification` was not fired :(

Any idea what is wrong ?

**NOTE**:  i don't know if it's matter but because i m not under xcode, i m under Delphi, i don't use the const

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * __nonnull const kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification;
```

but use my own NSString value who contain exactly `"kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification"`

any idea where the problem could be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observer will only fire when the token is initially created or refreshed. It seems like you added the code for observer *after* this had already happened.

This is one of the reason you should handle the token in two places:

- in your [main app flow wiith `[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token)
- by [monitoring for token (re)generation in [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#monitor-token-generation]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#monitor-token-generation)

Comment: thanks Frank, was not this but i found the raison, it's because i need to observe com.firebase.notif.refresh-token and not the word kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification